# Run rb-fsevent in the background

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, daemon, fsevents

I'm trying to use the Daemons gem to daemonize a process in the background.This process just checks for any change in a directory and reports it. I've used the Daemons gem before and never really ran into any problems, however when I mix it with the rb-fsevent directory monitoring, something seems to go wrong.

Here's the ruby code that monitors the directory change,

```
require 'rb-fsevent'
require 'rubygems'

notifier = FSEvent.new
notifier.watch "/Test/NewFolder" do |directories|
  puts "Detected change inside: #{directories.inspect}"
end
notifier.run
```

And here's how I'm calling the ruby file,

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'daemons'

Daemons.run('folder_watcher_mac.rb')
```

When I run "ruby start_watcher.rb start" nothing is happening. Is this the right way to daemonize the rb-fsevent?

Comment: From what I've read, the process will be detached from the console. So the output you are giving with `puts` wont be of any use. You might have to look around other ways to inform changes, maybe use a log.

Comment: Yes. That's what I thought. So I tried to delete that folder whenever I manually created it. But that didn't work either.

Comment: I didn't really get what you meant by deleting the folder whenever you created it.

Comment: You want a notification of any kind to inform you that something has changed inside the directory you gave to watch, right ?

Comment: I actually want to run a script whenever a new folder/file has been created in the directory I'm watching. ( What I meant earlier was that when ever I create a folder inside a watched folder, the daemon process will delete it. Instead of writing it to the log, I was just fooling around. Not very efficient! )

Comment: Okay. So did the logging work ? What about trying to run `folder_watcher_mac.rb` as a blocking process in the console (not as a background process), is it working ? And are you sure the daemonized process have permissions to delete the files in that directory ?